# Unable to hit route dialogflow in firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, openai-api

I am trying to make a GC chat integrated Dialogflow bot integrated with openAI in firebase cloud function. I am unable to hit /dialogflow, I am getting this error: "Cannot GET /dialogflow".
I am using Node.js.All other routes are working fine. Below is the code in app.js, I have two other files server.js and index.js.  please help.
Here is my code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const {Configuration, OpenAIApi} = require("openai");
require("dotenv").config();


const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

const express = require("express");
const {WebhookClient} = require("dialogflow-fulfillment");
const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("online"));
app.post("/dialogflow", express.json(), (req, res) => {
  const prompt = new WebhookClient({request: req, response: res});

  /**
 * A function to welcome the user to the agent.
 * @param {Object} agent - The Dialogflow agent object.
 */
  function welcome() {
    prompt.add("Welcome to my agent!");
  }
  /**
 * Generates text using the OpenAI API.
 *
 * @async
 * @function
 * @param {string} prompt - The text prompt to generate a response for.
 * @return {Promise<{status: number, response: string}>} - A promise that resolves to an object with a status code and response text.
 */
  async function queryGPT(prompt) {
    try {
      const response = await openai.createCompletion({
        model: "text-davinci-003",
        prompt: `Human: ${prompt}\nAI: `,
        temperature: 0.9,
        max_tokens: 500,
        top_p: 1,
        frequency_penalty: 0,
        presence_penalty: 0.6,
        stop: ["Human:", "AI:"],
      });

      return {
        status: 1,
        response: `${response.data.choices[0].text}`,
      };
    } catch (error) {
      return {
        status: 0,
        response: "",
      };
    }
  }

  const intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set("Default Welcome Intent", welcome);
  intentMap.set("Default Fallback Intent", queryGPT);
  prompt.handleRequest(intentMap);
});

module.exports =app;
```

My code for server.js :

```
const app = require("./app");

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

My code for Index.js

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const app = require("./app");

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your /dialogflow route is set up to respond to POST requests:

```
app.post("/dialogflow", express.json(), (req, res) => { ... }
```

It will not work with GET.

Comment: How do i solve it?

Comment: Replace post with get if you want get?  Your question isn't clear what you need this code to do.

Comment: Sorted. It worked fine when I deployed it. Seems like firebase function has some problem testing locally. Thanks